# How to convert datatable rows to array?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have to convert this rows to array per column in selected rows, i used C# MVC.

This is the view before and after click :

[Selecting rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMgb0.png)
[after click the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fR7mz.png)

here's the code :

```
@if (Model != null)
    {

        <table id="tablePenerima" class="table table-striped table-bordered animate__animated animate__fadeInRight" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <thead>
                <tr>

                    @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Tables[0].Columns)
                    {

                        <th align="center">@col.ColumnName</th>
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    <tr>

                        @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Tables[0].Columns)
                        {
                            <td align="center">@row[col.ColumnName]</td>
                        }

                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
    else
    {
        <p style="color:red;"> Mohon upload file dahulu </p>
    }

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="button" name="Blast" id="btnBlast" class="btn btn-lg btn-success"><span><i class="fas fa-bolt"> &nbsp; </i></span>BLAST</button>
    </div>
```

and the JS :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#tablePenerima').DataTable({
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [

                'selectAll',
                'selectNone',

            ],
            select: true
        });

        $('#tablePenerima tbody').on('click', 'tr', function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('selected');
        });
        $('#btnBlast').click(function () {
            var rowdata = table.rows('.selected').data().toArray();
            var msg = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < rowdata.length; i++) {
                msg += rowdata[i]+ '\n'
            }
            alert(msg);
        })

    });
```

That's all. I want to change the output to be [array0] [array1] [array2] [array4] by per column because i want to use them in futher validation and method inside FOR condition in JS.
Thank you :)

Comment: I am sorry because i dont include the c# code because the main problem is in JS.

Comment: I removed that because if there is C# tag then C# expert also found this when they search but they will not give you answer because it JS related issue.

Comment: ok thank you. btw can you solve the exisisting problem?

Comment: my bad, now I see you put C# and asp.net mvc code. I rollback it. by the way, it seems you already converted into array for selected rows. what was the issue after that? moreover, can you please prepare a codesandbox

Comment: im sorry , the output that i want is like a split array because i want to make a validation per column in the next

Comment: Let's clarify: do you need to convert your `rowdata` from 1-level array (`[ v1, v2, v3 ... ]`) to wrapped (`[ [ v1 ], [ v2 ], [ v3 ] ... ]`)?

Comment: yes, for sure. That's that i want

Comment: @SigitBudi can you please update your question to provide exact sample output. both source data and output data with array notation. that will be clear picture what you want

Comment: im sorry for this queston i havr found the aswer. thanks for your help :)

Comment: @SigitBudi - Please update the question with the answer found.